# HiveAccessControlException Permission denied: user [hive] does not have [ALL] privilege on [hdfs://sandbox-....:8020/user/..] (state=42000,code=40000)

Tags: hadoop, hive, permission-denied, hortonworks-sandbox

When I'm trying to load a CSV file from local hadoop on sandbox to hive table, I'm getting the following exception

```
LOCATION 'hdfs://sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com:8020/user/maria_dev/practice';                                                                 
Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: HiveAccessControlException Permission denied: user [hive] does not have [ALL] privilege on [hdfs://sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com:8020/user/ma
ria_dev/practice] (state=42000,code=40000)
```

I used the following code, can you please suggest a solution for this?

```
CREATE TABLE Sales_transactions(
Transaction_date DATE,
Product STRING,
Price FLOAT,
Payment_Type STRING,
Name STRING,
City STRING,
State STRING,
Country STRING,
Account_Created TIMESTAMP,
Last_Login TIMESTAMP,
Latitude FLOAT,
Longitude FLOAT,
Zip STRING
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
STORED AS TEXTFILE
**LOCATION 'hdfs://sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com:8020/user/maria_dev/practice';** //Error pointing this line.
```

Answer (score 0):

It is actually two step process and i think you missed step1.(Assuming your user have all proper access.)
Step 1 - Load local file into hdfs file system.

```
hdfs dfs -put /~/Sales_transactions.csv hdfs://sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com:8020/user/maria_dev/practice`
```

Step 2 - Then load above hdfs data into the table.

```
load data inpath 'hdfs://sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com:8020/user/maria_dev/practice/Sales_transactions.csv' into table myDB.Sales_transactions_table
```

Alternately you can use this as well -

`LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '/~/Sales_transactions.csv' INTO TABLE mydb.Sales_transactions_table;`